# Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-multidex

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.1, I started to get following error during build. Project uses multidex and DX is enabled by default as you would notice in the error. I tried to check dependency graph to understand what is going on but so far have no clue. Interestingly this only fails on my machine. I cleaned up everything, including reinstall etc but nothing worked.

Anyone had the same issue and how did you solve it? Or any direction that I can take a look?

```
AGPBI: {
    "kind":"error",
    "text":"Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat",
    "sources":[{}],
    "tool":"D8"
}
```

This is the task that fails:

```
transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug
```

I checked similar issues and it seems random things fixes their problem, I'm not sure what is the real cause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to determine the root cause by using the following steps. It may be different use case for each issue, therefore this is the way to determine the root cause.

- Go to android studio
- Navigate -> Class
- Check `include non-project classes`
- Copy paste full class path with package name. `android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat`
- You should be able to see where it is used. Most probably you may need to remove it from one of them.

In my case the issue was ViewPagerIndicator library was downloading support library as jar. Removing it solved the issue.

Comment: I removed viewpager indicator library and works fine.. fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1

Comment: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat In This case what to do?

Answer (score 15):

For my solution (I do not know it will work for you):

Firstly I followed `@Orhan Obut's` solution:

[Search for duplicate classes in your project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50147985/787399)

I found that there are more than one class files in different libraries.

Then I put the ignore annotation above my support dependency in my project module's build.gradle (app folder):

```
 //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

I realized that ignorance is no solution, because the error did not go away, even after clean-rebuilding and clearing/invalidating cache for the project.

See: [Infographic: 11 Most Common Android Errors and How to Fix Them](https://www.codementor.io/android/tutorial/most-common-android-errors-how-to-fix-them)

So I explored more, and found out this link:

[Android - Understanding and dominating gradle dependencies](https://www.devsbedevin.com/android-understanding-gradle-dependencies-and-resolving-conflicts/)

It suggests ways to resolve conflicts. Hence I put this on my gradle just above the declarations of dependencies:

```
configurations.all {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}
```

Since then when I search for duplicate classes for this one using `@Orhan Obut's` solution above, I find only single entry in the result. That meant that there were no duplicates.

Also, it will be better if you migrate to AndroidX with latest SDK and build tools. Make sure you don't have older support dependencies anywhere.

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: You need to find out which class is duplicate from different versions.

Answer (score 13):

I have my solution by change this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

it works for me.

Comment: This didn't work me unfortunately. Interestingly, everything works for everyone else but me.

Answer (score 6):

For the easy option just add

```
configurations.all {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'}
```

before dependencies in build.gradle app module, it should ignore v4 support libraries, and the duplicate error will go away.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the below line in the build.gradle of the app level worked for me

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me this helps to resolve such issues

all support libraries (also included thirdy-part) reduces to specified version

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '28.0.0-beta01'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem just a while ago. In my case the third party library used the older AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat version v4 22 and i already updated to newer one v4 28 so both support library classes clashed

Answer (score 0):

In y case I've resolved issue by

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
```

to

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

some third-party library may be use different version of support library. you can use `./gradlew :app:dependencies` find out it, and then import the current version of the support library.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have my solution by change this :
android / build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = "27.0.3"
    }
}
to
buildscript {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = "26.0.0"
    }
}
directory android / app / build.gradle
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```