# One Thing to Ask about Build.Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build

I was building this movie-directory using Android. Everything seems OK as I was following a Udemy video step by step. But when I tried to run this thing, I kept getting this message as follows:

**Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

Everything else seems fine. While searching for the answer for this problem, I found that it has to do with Build.Gradle(App). For that reason, I would like to show you my Build.Gradle(App) and ask someone for help. My Build.Gradle is as follows...

```
 **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mike.sideproject_mymoviecollection"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
    'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
    }
   dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.dubsmash.volley:library:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso-sample:2.5.2'
    }**
```

So if anyone knows how to resolve this problem, please let me know!
Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786779/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-accessibilityservice-acc)

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the dependencies. If you type "gradlew app:dependencies" in Android Studio (AS) terminal, you will see the dependency graph. The issue occurs when one dependency uses one version on the library where as another dependency might be using another version of the same library. AS makes sure we use the same dependency across the application and hence this error. Once you figure out which dependency is causing this issue, you can exclude that version of the library from your dependency as follows :
implementation ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }