# Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat? this appears to me when compiling

Tags: android-studio

The error below appears after compiling.

[image]

How can I prevent this error from occuring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786779/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-accessibilityservice-acc)

Comment: It would be helpful to others if you shared what you already tried when you say _"I have tried everything"_. That way, you'll show that you made an effort to try and fix this on your own, and so that people won't be suggesting solutions that you may have already tried.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, I will take your comment very seriously

Comment: Can you edit your question with the app.gradle file ? If your problem have not solved yet.