# When updating the android api to the latest one, I got this error

Tags: android, android-studio

Program type already present: android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat

What does this mean ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Program type already present" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676155/what-does-program-type-already-present-mean)

Comment: Maybe this questioncan help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786779/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-accessibilityservice-acc

Comment: For a moment I thought that this guy was using eclipe ide...lol