# I made an apk and gave this error here: Program type already present: android.support.v4.provider.DocumentsContractApi19

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I made a mistake that was happening in the layout, everything worked out, I was not giving any more mistakes, then I got this error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.provider.DocumentsContractApi19

My build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tdl.com.dindim"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.adefruandta.spinningwheel:spinningwheel:0.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    implementation 'org.immutables:gson:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My Androidmanifest (I do not know if this can help)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tdl.com.dindim">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/dindimlogo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/dindimlogo"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.noTitle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.tdl.com.dindim"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="My Dashboard"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.SignupActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.noTitle" />
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.SpinActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_spin"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.ProfileActivity"
            android:label="Profile"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.WithdrawActivity"
            android:label="Withdraw"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.WithdrawRequestActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="tdl.com.dindim.activities.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.noTitle"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is the complete error
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:127)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList$MainDexListException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v4.provider.DocumentsContractApi19
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.D8MainDexListTransform.transform(D8MainDexListTransform.kt:114)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v4.provider.DocumentsContractApi19
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: try looking at this similar post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49786779/error-program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-accessibilityservice-acc

Comment: Refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56911770/10271334

Comment: thanks Jeel and @a-local-nobody 
you helped me

Comment: is not giving any more error, but my app does not work on the mobile

Comment: Refer to this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205825/android-studio-error-while-generating-the-main-dex-list